# j-easy/easy-rules how the rule inference work

Tags: java, rule-engine

Are we able to do the similar action like in `drools`, we use `update(fact)` or `modify(fact)` to enter the inference loop again (evaluate -> agenda -> execute). My question is, are we able to control that in Java [easy-rules](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules)? What is the rule inference algorithm that is implementing in easy-rules?

Drools example:

```
rule "Every person named Mario is a male" when
    $person : Person( firstName == "Mario" )
then
    modify ( $person )  { setMale( true ) }
end
```

Comment: From the docs it looks very much like easy rules is very ... simple. This is not a full JSR94 implementation but simply a condition chaining api.

Comment: Also note that from the docs it doesn’t use Rete - but a very naive “loop through rules and see what matches”.  This performs _very poorly_ for all but trivial rule sets. TBH this looks like someone’s toy project - not a production ready codebase.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see... I thought this is good choice due to its simplicity as we need something that is more portable onto different jvm... looks like have to look for different options...